# Appium device name cannot be blank

Tags: android, json, appium

Currently, I am working on appium. I write test cases for my app and try to run a mobile test with appium. In the beginning, it gives the error for Android sdk. I set the path and environment variable to handle this issue. Then, when I fill the desired capabilities, it gives an error either "device name cannot be blank" or "You must include a platform name capability".  [image: Appium Desktop Error]

Comment: If you provide app, you don't need to provide appPackage and appActivity. Try removing appPackage and appWaitActivity

Comment: I have solved this issue by changing the UiAutomator name. Now I am taking the following error, "The instrumentation process cannot be initialized. Make sure the application under the test does not crash and investigate the logcat outpıt". If you can help me, I will be grateful.

Comment: You need to check full log to know about the cause of error